# Using bootstrap 4 I cant get my buttons to the same size

Tags: button

Using bootstrap 4 I can't get my buttons the same size. The 2000 buttons are bigger thant the 199x ones :
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1stX.jpg)

```
                <div class="row">
                <div class="d-inline p-1"><a class="btn btn-info btn-block" href="ram_issues_1997.php" role="button">1997</a></div>
                <div class="d-inline p-1"><a class="btn btn-info btn-block" href="ram_issues_1998.php" role="button">1998</a></div>
                <div class="d-inline p-1"><a class="btn btn-info btn-block" href="ram_issues_1999.php" role="button">1999</a></div>
                <div class="d-inline p-1"><a class="btn btn-info btn-block" href="ram_issues_2000.php" role="button">2000</a></div>
                <div class="d-inline p-1"><a class="btn btn-info btn-block" href="ram_issues_2001.php" role="button">2001</a></div>
                <div class="d-inline p-1"><a class="btn btn-info btn-block" href="ram_issues_2002.php" role="button">2002</a></div>
                <div class="d-inline p-1"><a class="btn btn-info btn-block" href="ram_issues_2003.php" role="button">2003</a></div>
                <div class="d-inline p-1"><a class="btn btn-info btn-block" href="ram_issues_2004.php" role="button">2004</a></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion they are the same size, I check your image and run your code and in my browser (Google Chrome) I parse them with "inspect element" and they are all 60.5 x 38

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).